# ReactJS : Form Data Capture : values not setting properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying out with a small react app, with a form based data capture, after keying in the values, when user clicks submit button, values need to be captured in state variable. But, state variable contains null value in handleSubmit function. For clarity, code snippets are given below,

Constructor code, for the sake of completeness/clarity,

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        username : '', 
    };
}
```

handleChange function is where I set state variable,

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState( [event.target.username]: event.target.value );
}
```

handleSubmit function is where, I print state variable, which **contains null value**, instead of user inputted value.

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.state.username);
}
```

Component's render function is given below, which invokes handleChange 
 and handleSubmit.

```
render() {
return(
    <div>
    <form>
    <label>
        Title:
        <input 
            type = "text"
            name="username" 
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}/>
    </label>
            <button 
            label="Submit" 
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Submit
    </button>
    </form>
        </div>
)};
```

I am missing on something. I am new to react. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2):

you need setState's argument to be an object.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.username]: event.target.value });
}
```